# "Unusual" question about e-commerce application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree, prestashop

Is it possible to merge two apps, one e-commerce application based on PrestaShop with second one "ordinary" build on Rails?

Is that even possible? Which issues I would encountered during building that application?
Or maybe I just saying "stupid things" and that is a very bad idea?

-

Second one approach is to use Spree with Rails. However I heard that Spree is much slower than PrestaShop and doesn't have much modules.
Advantages on Spree are that my skills at Ruby are much more superior than in PHP, so I would mastered Spree much faster than PrestaShop.

I have practically zero experience with both sollutions(Spree, PrestaShop).

Priority in choosing option is "how much time it would take" and quality of final application(this order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are weighing the advantages and disadvantages of several solutions and can't decide which one to pick, so you wonder whether it makes sense to use more than one. The answer is **usually no**. Even though it may be possible, multiple technologies are much more difficult to set up and maintain than choosing one single technology. I strongly advise against it.

Even if one particular solution doesn't have all the features you need (e.g. specific modules), it's usually much easier to simply write those features yourself than to add a completely different technology to your stack. I say usually because as always, there are exceptions, but only in rare cases where some highly specific feature is needed.

It's true that Rails apps are sometimes (not always) slower than PHP apps, but the speed difference only becomes relevant if you need to scale to a very large number of users (millions). And even at those high scales, Rails will perform well if you're smart about setting up your server infrastructure, make use of caching, etc.

Finally, I would personally recommend Spree over Prestashop, but that's a matter of opinion. If you already have experience with Ruby, I definitely recommend Spree.